# MP4 video - Editing Creation Date and Other Metadata

Tags: video, ffmpeg, date, timestamp

I wish to find out if it is possible to edit the creation date and time of an MP4 video file. I have attempted to do so using `ffmpeg` with the syntax listed below.

```
ffmpeg -y -i "22.mp4" -c copy -map_metadata -1 -metadata creation_time=2016-09-20T21:30:00 "23.mp4"
```

However, this also edits other metadata like the vendor used to create the file, etc. Is it possible for someone who is knowledgeable with `ffmpeg` or any other tools which can do what I require to assist ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104641/how-do-i-find-the-date-a-video-avi-mp4-was-actually-recorded

Comment: I've tried using taglib as mentioned in the post but you cannot edit the ta for vendor/tagtype.

Comment: Did you found the solution without having to use an app created by somebody? I need something similar to your question, with a command line. If so, please add it to the Response section and mark it as Reponse, it will help others.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my [dmMediaConverter](http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html) ...a ffmpeg GUI exposing some of its features.
Just press Run Now and choose a output file name ... don't forget to put the mp4 extension (newfile.mp4).

[image]

Comment: I do not believe this answers the question. I think n00b2120 wants to just edit or add specific metadata (while leaving others untouched) and re-mux, not re-encode as your screenshot seems to suggest.

Comment: As my screenshot shows i add to the container creation_time metadata, without touching anything else, coping the streams, without re-encoding. It is exactly what  n00b2120 wants.

Comment: I see. It was the "Job Type: Convert" that made me assume otherwise.

Comment: it's a nice app, and does the trick pretty neat, cheers